# how to skip banners while login into remote machine using expect script?

Tags: linux, expect

My `expect` script is trying to run the below command to copy a script to remote host:

```
spawn scp -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no     /tmp/rem_script.sh $env(user_name)@$env(first_db_node_ip):/tmp
expect "assword"
send -- "$env(rem_password)\r"
expect eof
```

But unfortunately remote host is having banner like below, since the banner contains the word password, `expect` script sends the pwd before the correct expect prompt

Banner:

```
================================================================
For password resets, please call the Helpdesk xxx-xxx-xxxx
================================================================
```

Comment: please note i can change expect as "assword:" but for each host it will differ so looking fior something like skipping banner

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try running `scp` with option `-o LogLevel=error`.

Another thing you could do is not use `expect` at all, but use ssh keys for authentication instead of passwords.